# ASP.NET Web API read model inside action filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a special case when I need to get some data from request body (or model let say) inside action filter (AuthorizationFilterAttribute). I have found this way:

```
public async override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var model = await actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsAsync<XYZ>();
    var valueINeed = model.Something;
    etc...
}
```

This works fine but unfortunately after calling ReadAsAsync<> once it is not possible to read model again (I guess that ReadAsAsync<> move position in underlining stream). Because it can't be read again model not make it into controller action:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Put([FromBody]XYZ order)
{
    // order is null here
}
```

Any thoughts how to read model in action filter or how to work around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Web API, the response body is a read forward only stream. So once you read it, you cannot read it again.

Consider passing the `something` in query params or [some other parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21351714/244353), other than body.