# POST a multiple fragment JSON using Postman with application/json header

Tags: c#, json, postman, webapi

I have the following JSON

```
{"name":"tester1","type":"frontend"}
{"name":"tester2","type":"midlleware"}
{"name":"tester3","type":"backend"}
```

When I paste the above into Postman with an application/JSON, only the 1st row/JSON will be passed to the function because of the lack of commas between each row. Note, I cannot change the incoming JSON format nor the Content-Type (application/JSON). Also note this is a valid multipart JSON
[See here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadMultipleContentWithJsonReader.htm)

**My API method is as follows:**

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ProcessJson([FromBody] string _incomingJSON)
```

Note: I can change my signature **([FromBody] string _incomingJSON)**

_incomingJSON is null if I use application/JSON but populated if I use text/plain (which I can't use)

Is there any way I can handle this format with application/JSON and not get _incomingJSON as null?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should be able to get the raw POST data as a stream using [Getting raw POST data from Web API method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13226817/3744182) and then deserialize as shown in [Line delimited json serializing and de-serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29729063/3744182).

Comment: Can you add any other example endpoint where we can try this ?

Answer (score -1):

You should send with Postman in 3 rows like this:

[image: as you see in the Postman picture]

Comment: thanks, @salah, but I can't send 3 separate rows. the JSON comes in a bulk JSON input. I'm using Postman on;y for test purposes, the actual Post will come from an external server

Comment: You can get the bulk JSON and split it into an array of jsons